# Memory growth in Vaadin application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

We have found extreme memory use of an instance of `com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator`
[image]

[image]
Version: 8.5.2

Application is websocket event driven UI.

It appears that this happens sometimes when user suspends computer and vaadin hasn't destroyed the session yet.

Heap dump shows that atmosphere connection is still in CONNECTED state.
Vaadin heartbeats are 60 seconds.

Please advise what other info might be useful.  This doesn't happen consistently enough to reproduce.

Comment: Some additional pieces of information that could help understand what's going on here are what component type (e.g. Grid or ComboBox) the data communicator instance belongs to and any insights about the contents of the maps in the key mapper, e.g. size of the maps and any ideas on whether the contained item instances can would be active or stale based on whatever the application tries to show to the user.

Comment: The component is a Grid.

Comment: Grid is backed by a very small map for it's 'items'.  Map contents gets swapped and DataProvider is refreshed.

KeyMapper details coming shortly. Need to recompute heap.

Comment: KeyMapper:
keyObjectMap.size = 678
objectIdKeyMap.size=678

If this is supposed to be the number of rows in the grid in 'normal' operations, this should only have a size of about 6.

Comment: The question is I don't see where these 2gb is being retained. It isn't the maps

Comment: It is retained by those two maps together. Since both maps have references to the same items, neither of the maps are reported to on their own retain the memory. It's still an interesting question how 678 items can retain that much memory, but that's a different question.

Comment: It was expected that only about 6 of these large items would be kept in memory per grid instance, but if these get queued up sending to the browser, then they could accumulate to that large.  Is there anyway we can limit the pending queue size?

Comment: I have some ideas about why those items would accumulate, but I'd have to take the time to try to replicate to easily verify my ideas. One workaround that you could try is to postpone the actual update for the Grid instance until the overrideable `beforeClientResponse` method is run in the component that manages the grid.

Comment: Sorry for this question, but do you mean something like:

1) `ui.Access(() -> modify map);` backing grid, don't call refresh on data provider
2) `beforeClientResponse(){ dataProvider.refresh() }`

Maybe i'm way off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188495/discussion-between-pschmeltz-and-leif-astrand).

Comment: Something is keeping the HTTP session alive after timeouts. Start from the basics and check that you have meaningful HTTP session timeout and heartbeat values. If you see a memory leak, there must be a back reference to you your application UI or session. Make sure to clean up those references when UI gets disconnected.

Comment: Unfortunately I @eeq is correct. Looks like a background task might be the only one hanging on to the UI holding this connector. Will try to see if reproduce-able after correcting this.